# Is it possible to prevent all users (including super user) from deleting a specific application?

Tags: linux, administration

Is it possible to turn an application into a kind of a system one (like "Settings" or "GNOME software") so that no user including the super user could delete it?

Comment: You can't normally prevent the root user from deleting files unless you put them in a partition mounted as read-only (but the root user could still re-mount it and delete the files). Applications installed outside of home directories are usually in directories owned by root, which means ordinary users can't delete them.  Please update your question with an example of your issue, or some context to your question. For example, are interested in _malicious_ or _accidental_ deletion?

Comment: Also consider how you envisage _updating_ the software that you need/want to protect in this way (which usually involves replacing files, including executables).

Comment: Please indicate if you mean “delete” as in delete the files on disk, or if you mean remove through the package management interface.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the distro’s package manager.

For Fedora and RHEL8, you can just add the name to a .conf file in `/etc/dnf/protected.d/` and it can’t be [removed](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/conf_ref.html).  Older, yum based distros have a similar setting in `/etc/yum`.

For Debian-based distros, I think you can set a pkgCacheGen::ForceEssential setting in your `apt.conf` on packages, but I’m not sure (not my area of expertise).  You can apt-mark a package but that will also prevent updates.

Comment: I fail to understand how this prevents root to rm immediately whatever and, in particular, the (/usr)/bin executable.

Comment: Did you see when the question mentioned “Settings” and “GNOME Software”?  I interpreted the question to be about preventing uninstall.  There’s certainly no immutable flag on the files included in those packages.

Comment: Fair enough then! I had personally read that "turn an application into a kind of" was implying that the application had not been installed by any package manager... So... Yes indeed, OP should detail more so that we don't have to assume.

Answer (score 0):

The proper (and possibly most convenient) way to follow in order to prevent the **immediate** removal of a file (by its owner or even by root) is to go with the file attributes :

quoting *man chattr*

> A file with the 'i' attribute cannot be modified: it cannot be deleted
> or renamed… and the file can not be opened in write mode.

Therefore simply `chattr +i yourfile`

You can check the setting of the *immutable* attribute : `lsattr yourfile`

And verify that `rm yourfile` or even `sudo rm yourfile` wont delete anything, reporting instead :

`rm: cannot remove 'yourfile': Operation not permitted`

Of course, as written in some comment above, root can hopefully do whatever it wants to, including… reseting the file attributes.
So all you can expect is preventing from **immediate** deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Since the application is a *system* application, I would use read-only media (say a DVD, or an USB drive with the read only switch if all access to it is to be done remotely).

Basically, it would behave like a live distribution, or like firmware. If needed you can then add other options for persistence and/or a read/write filesystem (another media, memory, ...).

Not even root will be able to *remove* it.

Note that root could still evade that, not by erasing it (your question), but by *making it unavailable*, for example by mounting another filesystem on `/usr/bin` (if that's where your application is located) with the same contents, except your file. So if you really want to prevent root to do anything, you will need to make sure circumvent tools/devices/modules are not available.

One day you will have to update it, then you could burn a new image (fully or by using multiple sessions) move the read-only switch from the media while updating, reflash ...

Comment: If you are interested in an implementation of an immutable OS like this, please check out Fedora Silverblue. https://silverblue.fedoraproject.org/